# Importing from sibling directories (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-import, setup.py

I can't figure out how to import modules from sibling directories in Python 3 using absolute imports.

1. modify the `sys.path`.
2. turn the directory into a pip installable package via `__init__.py` and `setup.py`.

For option 1. I figured out how to import modules from sibling directories by modifying the `sys.path`, but this method seems a little hackey to me. Also, I've read that it is not preferred. Why? Is there something inherently wrong or dangerous about modifying the `sys.path`?

For option 2. What exactly do I need to do make my package pip installable? I've alreay created my `__init__.py` file, but it seems that I need to create and configure a `setup.py` script to prepare my package for distribution? I'm still in the development mode, so is this really the best/pythonic method? If it is, then do I just type `python setup.py install` into my terminal after creating the `setup.py`?

*Edit: I'm now trying to figure this out using absolute imports as python 3 does support relative imports.*

Answer (score 2):

> From what I've read, Python 3 does not support relative imports

It does.

To import `myproject/foo/__init__.py` from `myproject/bar/baz.py`, you can use this:

```
from .. import foo
```

Or if you want to import an object/module in `foo`:

```
from ..foo import object
```

This requires `myproject` to be a package, so `myproject/__init__.py` has to exist.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out when I'm at home. What about absolute imports? Is it possible to import modules across different directories using absolute imports without modifying the sys.path?

Comment: The "relative imports" that are not supported by Python 3 are the implicit ones: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references